# How can I validate if the column exist in a DataRow object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
private int EmploymentID { get; set; }

private void MapFields(DataRow row)
{
        if(row.HasError)
          EmploymentID = Convert.ToInt32(row["EmploymentID"].ToString());
}
```

The code shows that it validates if the DataRow object has error on its row but I want to validate if it ever exist. Is there an approach for the code rather using HasError method of DataRow?

Thank you for any kind answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DataRow has a Table property, referencing the [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that it came from. 
DataTable has a Columns property, which is a [DataColumnCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9d8d70f.aspx).

Enumerating this list will let you determine if the table contains the column you want. Note that ALL rows on the table have identical columns.

eg:

```
bool containsColumn = row.Table.Columns.Any(column => column.ColumnName == "EmploymentID");
```

It's worth pointing out that you will likely need to check for equality to [DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx), unless you are 100% certain the EmploymentID can never be returned null.

Also, if the EmploymentID column is typed as an integer, then you can avoid any need for type conversion, by using a direct cast:

```
EmploymentID = (int)row["EmploymentID"];
```

or alternatively, use [DataRowExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx) for a much neater approach, which does all the null checking for you:

```
EmploymentID =  row.Field<int?>("EmploymentID");
```

If EmploymentID isn't a nullable int, then you can coalesce the value like:

```
EmploymentID =  row.Field<int?>("EmploymentID") ?? 0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Will. You're answer is great.

Comment: @Hughes There are no extension method Any for DataColumnCollection. At least not in .NET 4.0.

Comment: @Irshad - [Any is in namespace System.Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972\(v=vs.100\).aspx), signature ```public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)```

Comment: @Hughes I know that. I added. But .Any is not for DataColumnCollection. Please check it on VS IDE.

Comment: @Irshad .Any extends any IEnumerable. DataColumnCollection implements InternalDataCollectionBase, which implements IEnumerable.  If you have an issue, you should log another question, not add it as more comments here.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use this one statement

```
row.Table.Columns.Contains("EmploymentID")
```