# Verify that a column exists in the DataRow before reading its value

Tags: c#

How do I write code that reads a DataRow but, if filed in DataRow isn't there, it just skips it and moves on, like this for example:

```
string BarcodeIssueUnit;
if (dr_art_line["BarcodeIssueUnit"].ToString().Length <= 0)
{
    BarcodeIssueUnit = "";
}
else
{
    BarcodeIssueUnit = dr_art_line["BarcodeIssueUnit"].ToString();
}
```

Now, the Column `BarcodeIssueUnit` can belong to the table but, in some cases, that column does not exist in the table. If it's not there and I read it, I get this error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Column `BarcodeIssueUnit` 
does not belong to table Line.
```

I just want to run a check if the column is there ok, let see the values, if it's not, just skip that part and go on.

Comment: VB, still a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984893/how-to-check-if-a-column-with-a-given-name-exists-in-a-datarow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I validate if the column exist in a DataRow object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677852/how-can-i-validate-if-the-column-exist-in-a-datarow-object)

Answer (score 51):

Check for column name using `DataRow.Table.Columns`. If there convert value else come out.

```
BarcodeIssueUnit = dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("BarcodeIssueUnit")?
                   dr_art_line["BarcodeIssueUnit"].ToString(): "";
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if(dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("BarcodeIssueUnit"))
{
    BarcodeIssueUnit = dr_art_line.Field<String>("BarcodeIssueUnit");
}
else
{
    BarcodeIssueUnit = String.Empty;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection.contains.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the table scheme for the current row contains a specific column:

```
 if (!dr_art_line.Table.Columns.Contains("BarcodeIssueUnit"))
 {
     BarcodeIssueUnit = "";
 }
 else
 {
      BarcodeIssueUnit = dr_art_line["BarcodeIssueUnit"].ToString();
 }
```